# How to add regression line to boxplot per group (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

i'm a begginer at R and I can't figure out how to add regression lines to my boxplot. My code (with data) is:

```
dat_full<-data.frame(Fuerza = c("19.6N","19.6N","58.8N","58.8N","98,0N","98,0N", "274.4N","274.4N"),
                     Músculo = c("Bíceps","Tríceps","Bíceps","Tríceps","Bíceps","Tríceps","Bíceps","Tríceps"),
                     mV.s = c(3.5227565, -0.0897375, 7.2907255, 1.8571375, 16.327445, 8.042295, 31.15557, 12.69073),
                     standdev = c(0.111590642, 0.187825239, 0.886093185, 0.16351915, 3.876932131, 2.637289091, 3.713413688, 1.262850285))

dat_full<- dat_full %>%
  mutate(Fuerza = factor(Fuerza, levels=c("19.6N","58.8N","98,0N","274.4N")))
dat_full


ggplot(dat_full, aes(x = as.factor(Fuerza),y=mV.s)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(lower = mV.s - standdev, upper = mV.s + standdev, middle = mV.s, 
                   ymin = mV.s - 3*standdev, ymax = mV.s + 3*standdev), stat = "identity")+
    facet_wrap(~Músculo)+
    xlab("Fuerza (N)")+
    theme_grey(base_size = 22)
```

which shows this plot

[image: Boxplot of two different groups with ggplot2]

What i need to do is to add a regression line for the means (mV.s) of every condition (Fuerza) for the two groups. It it's possible, I also want to visualize R2 and the regression equation on the graph.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add add a line to a ggplot using the `geom_smooth()` or `lm()` functions.  Given the line you need to create, it may be easier to just make the line using `lm()`.

`lm()` takes the parameters `data` and the two (or more) values you want to use in the regression. Here what you'd want to do is `{name_of_regression} <- lm(data = dat_full, {dependent_var}~{independent_var})`. I'm not sure what you want those variables to be, as Fuerza is currently populated with string values.

Also, it's been a little while since I've looked at R, so this is a somewhat verbose solution, but you can filter triceps and biceps into two datasets using the tidyverse package and then name make your regressions from each dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)
biceps <- filter(dat_full, dat_full$Musculo=="Biceps") 
biceps_reg <- lm(data = biceps, {biceps_dep}~{bicdeps_indep})
```

And repeat for triceps.

Then, make the ggplot you want, and using `geom_smooth()` insert your lm using:

```
ggplot({some_code}) +
   {...} +
   geom_smooth(method="lm", se = FALSE)
```

I know that doesn't really solve your problem of wanting to put the charts together, but you can save each ggplot for biceps and triceps and then put it together using `plot()` once you're done.

Also, here's an R tip: in RStudio you can check any function by using something like:

```
?plot
?lm
```

Apologies for the verbosity -- I wanted to provide a quick fix here, but others may have better advice. Additionally, please let me know what your independent and dependent variables would be for the regression (they have to both be numeric here, so Fuerza won't work).